# NTP timestamp in C program

Tags: c, ntp

I wish to write a C program which obtains the system time and hence
uses this time to print out its ntp equivalent.

Am I right in saying that the following is correct for the seconds part
of the ntp time?

```
long int ntp.seconds = time(NULL) + 2208988800;
```

How might I calculate the fraction part?

Comment: You might consider using time_t as target type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fractional part to add obviously is 0ps ... ;-)

So the question for the fraction could be reduced to how accurate is the system clock.

`gettimeofday()` gets you micro seconds. `clock_gettime()` *could* get you nano seconds.

Anyhow I doubt you'll be reaching the theoratically possible resolution the 32bit wide value for the fraction allows (at least on a standard PC).